# <asp> tag cannot recognized

Tags: asp.net, razor

I'am new to Asp.net MVC. I just downloaded a tutorial for learning. I copied their code into my "_Layout" file in order to make my view consistent. It cannot recognize the asp tag. I thought the error due to different view engine. I am using Razor engine. The code was

```
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
```

The error was

```
 unrecognized namcespace 'asp'
```

What does asp tag mean here? And how to swich it to Razor readable syntax.

Thanks

Comment: You can't use `<asp:>` in razor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asp tages can not be read in MVC when using Razor. You can either use ASP engine instead using Razor engine OR can use some MVC approach instead asp where it is being used